# SqlBulkCopy arithmetic overflow w/ .NET 4 - No issues with .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to insert a massive amount of data into my database using SqlBulkCopy.  I originally built this program using .NET 4.5 but it won't run on the older machine I need it to run on.  During testing (with 4.5) the program worked flawlessly however when I downgraded to .NET 4.0 it no longer works.

Here is the code:

```
string query = string.Format("Generic database query text");
OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
//insert the new records
SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString);

sbc.EnableStreaming = true;
sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 1200;
sbc.DestinationTableName = "TableName;
sbc.WriteToServer(reader);
```

In .NET 4.5 I can enable streaming while in .NET 4.0 I cannot.  Disabling streaming in .NET 4.5 does NOT break the solution.  This is the only difference between the code.  The columns in the table are mapped exactly 100000% 1:1.  Matching column names, matching data types, matching everything.  I've also tried manually mapping the columns using the code below, to no avail.

```
sbc.ColumnMappings.add("column1", "matchedColumn1");
```

The exact error I'm getting is:

```
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

But I know there are no large numbers being churned.  There is no math happening at all.  It's a simple query from one and insert into another.  I'm working with a small subset right now (for testing) where the IDs don't go above 5 digits and I've even tested changing all ints in the database to bigint.  Didn't work.

Columns:

```
1   - Int
A1  -Varchar(50)
19  -Varchar(50)
True    -bit
5/5/2011    -date
Passed InstaMed Standard Edits  -text
1   -int
C0200000000000000023    -varchar(100)
39  -int
82      -int
```

Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: Are you able to transfer *1* row?

Comment: No.  Even a single row produces the arithmetic error.

Comment: Please show the data of that single row

Comment: 1 A1 19 True 5/5/2011 Passed InstaMed Standard Edits 1 C0200000000000000023 39 82

Comment: May have no relevance whatsoever, but are you compiling a 64-bit or 32-bit exe?

Comment: 64 bit.  I tried 32 bit though.

Comment: I'm sure you've got your column mapped wrong somehow. Try this. Create  a new dummy table based on your destination table, but give it no constraints. Then, try sending one row, one column at a time. If you can send that column, try just sending column two, and so on.

Comment: Is that error an exception? If yes, can you show the stacktrace?